# Compulsory transformation between class and char *

Tags: c++

The following code is to test what will happen when a char* string is compulsorily transformed to a class pointer. In the class there are three string data and an integer. When I print the class as the string format, the data are listed as expected. But how can I know the value of the variable in the class? And why will this happen?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class IndexInfo
{
public:
    IndexInfo(string i,string t,string a,int ty)
    {indexName = i;tableName = t;Attribute = a;type = ty;}
    string indexName;
    string tableName;
    string Attribute;
    int type;
};

int main(){
    string a = "1234567890";
    printf("%ld",sizeof(a));
    printf("%ld",sizeof(string));
    char *b = "asdfghjkl1234567890";
    IndexInfo * c = (IndexInfo *) b;
    //cout << (*c).indexName << endl;
    printf("%s\n",c);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're lying to `printf`. Read the manual to learn its preconditions, and don't violate preconditions.

Comment: `*c` is not a valid `IndexInfo` instance. No member variables exist. You can't know the value of something that doesn't exist.

Comment: @molbdnilo: `char*` is allowed to alias stuff; I guess the lack of original construction is a deal-breaker here, but I think that's overly pedantic. If `IndexInfo` were a class suitable for binary [de]serialisation (it's not) this would be a pretty reasonable question.

Comment: Why are you using `printf` in C++ code;

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you expect the contents of the string `asdfghjkl1234567890` to be somehow assigned to `c->indexName`, `c->tableName` and `c->Attribute`.

In fact this isn't going to happen. A `string` is a class with it's own internal structure, not just a handful of `char`s. The binary layout of `string` is that it contains a pointer to `char`, not `char`s.

This means that casting a `char*` to an `IndexInfo*` will attempt to reinterpret characters `asdf` as a pointer to the internal buffer controlled by a `string`. `asdf` has hex values `61 73 64 47`, so by casting this will imply a pointer value `0x66647361`. Since this doesn't point to an internal buffer controlled by `string` this cast makes no sense.

You need to tell us what you are actually trying to achieve, then we can advise a good way to do it.